# Search for a symmetrical inner portion of a list

Tags: python, algorithm

What the code does: Takes a Python list of integers as input and searches for a 'symmetrical' inner-portion of the list. Example:

```
symmetrical_sum([10,8,7,5,9,8,15]) == ([8, 7, 5, 9, 8], 37)
```

Note: Symmetry occurs if the value of the ith element from the start of the list is equal to the value of the ith element from the end of the list.

```
def symmetrical_sum(a):
'''Takes a Python list of integers as input and searches for a 'symmetrical' inner-portion of the list 

Example: symmetrical_sum([10,8,7,5,9,8,15]) == ([8, 7, 5, 9, 8], 37) 

Symmetry occurs if the value of the ith element at the start of the list is equal to the value of the 
ith element at the end of the list'''  

#extract duplicate value
dupe = [x for n, x in enumerate(a) if x in a[:n]] 

#if no duplicate values found, do the following:
if dupe == []:
    middle = float(len(a))/2
    if middle % 2 != 0:
        sym = a[int(middle - .5):int(middle + .5)]
        ans = a[int(middle - .5)]
        tuple1 = (sym,ans)
    elif middle % 2 == 0:
        sym = a[int(middle - 1):int(middle + 1)]
        ans = sum(a[int(middle - 1):int(middle + 1)])//2
        tuple1 = (sym,ans)
    return tuple1
else:
    d_to_i = int("".join(map(str, dupe))) #convert duplicate value to integer
    p1 = a.index(d_to_i) #get index of first duplicate
    p2 = a.index(d_to_i, p1+1) #get index of second duplicate
    sym = a[p1:p2+1] #[symmetrical-portion]
    ans = sum(sym) #sum-of-symmetrical-portion
    tuple2 = (sym, ans)

return tuple2
```

Looking at my code I realize that it could probably be more efficient than this. It works, but I'm sure it could be better. I just don't possess the skills to 'compress it'. I've submitted my code already so this is just for my own personal development.

Comment: It is not a palindrome function

Comment: So to clarify, it's only symmetrical if the outer elements are the same, but the inner elements don't have to be?

So, [12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 90, 100, 4, 2, 6, 7, 22] would have an "symmetrical" sub list of [2, 3, 90, 100, 4, 2]?

Comment: Upon looking into this more. What is `symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5])` meant to return? Also what are `symmetrical_sum([1, 2])`, `symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3])` and `symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 4])` meant to return? This looks like it's _really_ not working as you intend.

Comment: @Acejhm yes, that is correct

Comment: @Peilonrayz `symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5])` would return `([1,2,1],4)`... the symmetrical numbers in your use case are the `1`'s. When it is `[1, 2, 3]` it would return the median which is `2` in this case. when it is `[1, 2, 3, 4]` again the median rule would apply, so `(2+3)\2 = 2.5`, but since it needs to be an `int` it would return `([2,3],2)`. You can put the code into an IDE to check it out. but I've tested all the cases I can think of and got what I expected. a zero would return `([0],0)`

Comment: And what should `[1, 2]` return?

Comment: Why is `[1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]` -> `[1, 2, 1]` when -0 is 5?

Comment: @Peilonrayz good question, I didn't use that as a test case, however the code would return `([1],1)`. I am not entirely sure what the correct output should be in that event. The autograder returned a pass on all it's test cases. I guess my supervisors didn't take a case like this into account so did not specify how to handle a case of 2 non-symmetrical values

Comment: @Peilonrayz reading your last question, I'm starting to think you do not entirely understand what the function is supposed to do. What do you think it does? The number on the outside of the `[ ]` is the sum of the sublist

Comment: I'm not talking about the sum, I'm talking about the "Symmetry occurs if the value of the ith element at the start of the list is equal to the value of the ith element at the end of the list" with `l = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5]` `l[0] != l[~0]`.

Comment: The code in the question doesn't work in the manner it's described to. I have highlighted this [in my disposable answer below](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/219256). [meta about disposable answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6977)

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is not working as intended.

1. > Symmetry occurs if the value of the ith element at the start of the list is equal to the value of the 
   >   ith element at the end of the list

   Meaning for any list `l` the symmetry occurs when `l[i] == l[~i]`.

   ```
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 1, 3, 4])
   ([1, 2, 1], 4)
   >>> symmetrical_sum([0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4])
   ([1, 2, 1], 4)
   ```

   This says that the midpoint is the same distance from the end of the list as the starting value. And it says 1 and -3 are the same distance.
2. No where does it say the input will only have one duplicate.

   ```
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1])
   ValueError: 21 is not in list
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2])
   ValueError: 12 is not in list
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2])
   ValueError: 12 is not in list
   ```
3. The output returns different amount of values when the size of the input are different multiples of two.

   ```
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2])
   ([1], 1)
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 4])
   ([2, 3], 2)
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
   ([3], 3)
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
   ([4, 5], 4)
   >>> symmetrical_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
   ([5], 5)
   ```